# Laravel/Lumen Using delay and onQueue at the same time

Tags: laravel, lumen

i want to use `delay` and  `onQueue` methods at same time but i'll get error:

```php
dispatch(new MyJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addHours(2))->onQueue('high');
```

> Error : Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Bus\PendingDispatch::delay()

But in normal laravel app i can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Queueable](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-what-does-every-trait-in-a-job-class-6039707b851b#:%7E:text=The%20Queueable%20trait,these%20properties%20before%20dispatching%20it.) trait in jobs